# Apache 2.4 will not connect on anything other than port 80

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I have opened up my dev machine to another developer. For added security, I am trying to enable port forwarding onto my local Apache 2.4 web server. BUT,It will not connect on anything other that port 80.  I have followed the various instructions given for example: [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940909/configure-apache-to-listen-on-port-other-than-80)

So, I have set the local port in my router to be 5070 (it could be anything, just not 80) and the "port range" to 80 using TCP as they are coming in off a browser. Then I change both the ports.conf (Listen 5070) file and the mysite.conf (`<VirtualHost *:5070>`) of these above files to both read 5070. My hosts file still reads local host as 127.0.0.1

I restart Apache but it just refuses to connect to my app. If I put everything back to port 80 things work. It does seem to matter if the Firewall is off or on.

The one thing that is really weird is that when I do a `netstat -tulpn` I get this: `tcp6 0   0 :::5079  :::* LISTEN 1702/apache2`

I never stipulated tcp6.

Any idea what I am missing?

Many thanks !

Comment: In addition to Lienhart Woitok's answer, you should know that using a different port doesn't increase security.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a slight misconception. If you forward port 80 to apache port 5070 you are still publicly available on port 80, what you are trying to avoid. You need to turn this around and open port 5070 on your router. You can forward that port to port 80 of your apache as your apache is not directly publicly reachable.

So put port 5070 in the port range of your router. Leave your apache on port 80 and put 80 as local port into your roter. Your friend connects to you by entering `http://your-ip-or-dyndns:5070` into the browser.

You can access your apache as before with `http://localhost`.

If you don't want anyone finding port 5070 open to access your apache, I would recommend to put authentication in front.

Comment: Thank you ! I have restricted access using "require ip" within Apache 2.4 
Question: adding authentication "in front"., does that happen in the router or where?

Comment: Question two: I am now confused, as the StackOverflow response which I featured in my question, states that you must change your ports.conf to the new IP within Apache, and well as the virtual host settings to the new IP. How does that fit when you recommend that the internal port stays at 80? 

Thank you !

Comment: Authentication can happen on apache. Google for 'apache basic auth', that should lead to enough results. Regarding port: that SO assumes a server directly connected to the internet. You are in a different situation. You have a router in front. You can change the port on apache as well, then you have to configure your router accordingly and access your apache using `http://localhost:5070`. But it is not necessary, the router translates port 5070 to 80 when configured as in my answer.